# strange msdos line in GRUB edit

Tags: grub2, hacking

While editing a GRUB entry, I saw the following code:

```
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then 
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 43b0d0ec-0d46-4963-a26c-67bb074606f7
else
  search --no floppy --fs uuid -- set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 43b0dec-0d46-4963-a26c-67
fi
linux            /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0.38-generic root=UUID=43b0d0ec-0d46-4963-a26c-67bb074606f7 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-38-generic
```

My question is whether this seems like a physical intrusion, since it refers something about `msdos`. I do not run any other  environment, but Lubuntu. Is it natural for the word `msdos` to be appearing here?

Instead of a hacking, could it be anything else? Could Wine be the element that is affecting this?

Answer (score 6):

`part_msdos` is the module used to access DOS partition *tables*. From the [GRUB documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Naming-convention.html):

> ```
> (hd0,msdos1)
> ```
>
> Here, ‘hd’ means it is a hard disk drive. The first integer ‘0’ indicates the drive number, that is, the first hard disk, the string ‘msdos’ indicates the partition scheme, while the second integer, ‘1’, indicates the partition number (or the PC slice number in the BSD terminology). The partition numbers are counted from one, not from zero (as was the case in previous versions of GRUB). This expression means the second partition of the first hard disk drive. In this case, GRUB uses one partition of the disk, instead of the whole disk.

---

> Is it natural for the word msdos to be appearing here?

[Yes](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Naming-convention.html).

Comment: Ok, undestood. And thank you for the answer. 
Though, I did not setup a partition of 1,6GB at the beginning.
Since this, would there be a chance of a hack through physical access?

Comment: And if so, could the existence of this partition be the reason for not being able to conclude the administrator password change from the recovery console?

Comment: No and no. And you probably did create it (ie. the system did it for you) if you use uefi.

Comment: If anyone else is confused about the "its the second partition, and indexing starts at 1" => on the linked docs the example is actually "hd0,msdos2" :)